# Are intoxicants other than alcohol forbidden?

Tags: halal-haram, alcohol

Regarding the forbidden part of alcohol, it's clear to me.

What my question here is: What about other kinds of intoxications apart from alcohol?  E.g., smoking joints/weed/marijuana & other drugs.

Anything separate mentioned for these or they classify in the same category as alcohol?  Because some of these don't drive you insane and out of senses as alcohol.

Comment: Anything that damages the human being is forbidden, as the Prophet PBUH said "إن لبدنك عليك حق", which means, your body has rights from you.

Comment: @AbdelRahmanShamel, My Brother, but that could be so many things. Even spices damage you.... excess of anything is bad for your body. 
I seek a clearer answer for my question.

Comment: Yes, anything in excess is not right, Allah says:"و كذلك جعلناكم أمة وسطا"even worshipping and praying in excess that u don't pay attention to other responsibilities is not right, and it can be a sin, but smoking and these stuff are particularly prohibited and haram, as it is crystal clear that they do nothing  but harm.

Comment: @AbdelrahmanRagab It is only *crystal clear* after recent medical studies that smoking does harm. Less than 50 years ago cocaine and smoking was prescribed by doctors to calm their patients down.

Answer (score 1):

In Islam Khumir (Arabic word for Wine) is Haram as Allah says:

[image]

> O you who have believed, indeed, intoxicants, gambling, [sacrificing on] stone alters [to other than Allah ], and divining arrows are but defilement from the work of Satan, so avoid it that you may be successful. [5:90]

Allah also says:

[image: enter preformatted text here]

> They ask you about wine and gambling. Say, "In them is great sin and [yet, some] benefit for people. But their sin is greater than their benefit." And they ask you what they should spend. Say, "The excess [beyond needs]." Thus Allah makes clear to you the verses [of revelation] that you might give thought. [2:219]

Now that we know that Khumir (wine) is forbidden by Allah, let's visit this [hadith](http://sunnah.com/nasai/51/48):

> أَخْبَرَنَا سُوَيْدٌ، قَالَ أَنْبَأَنَا عَبْدُ اللَّهِ، عَنْ مُحَمَّدِ بْنِ عَجْلاَنَ، عَنْ نَافِعٍ، عَنِ ابْنِ عُمَرَ، عَنِ النَّبِيِّ صلى الله عليه وسلم قَالَ ‏ "‏ كُلُّ مُسْكِرٍ حَرَامٌ وَكُلُّ مُسْكِرٍ خَمْرٌ ‏"‏ ‏.‏
>
> The Prophet [SAW] said: "Every intoxicant is unlawful and every intoxicant is Khumir ."

This means that anything that intoxicates you is Khumir, at the same level of forbiddance. This is the case because at the time of the Prophet there were other known intoxicants from many cultures, and the prophet forbade them all.

Same hadith was reported [multiple times](http://sunnah.com/search/?q=%D9%83%D9%84%20%D9%85%D8%B3%D9%83%D8%B1) as well. This intoxicants include Weed, Drugs, Marijuana, etc.. Those will make you lose your mind (in some cases worst than light drinking).

Smoking on the other hand has a different ruling. It is not an intoxicant, but keeps you alert. This is the same as Coffee, tea, [Khat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Khat) (a Yemenite plant). Scholars are divided on the issue of smoking, some say it is not Haram and some say it is. Those who say it is, say it is because of the many harmful additive cigarettes contain and for the fact that nicotine is addictive.

Answer (score 0):

Anything that can make you drunk, as in the state of sukara, falls under the general prohibition.

Sukt is something that influences us until we don't know what we're saying.  Just think about a person who's drunk and blabbering on without being aware, wakes up and doesn't know how they got there.  Whatever can cause that is prohibited.  It can be certain types of drugs like crystal meth, PCP, crack...

Allah says:

**"O ye who believe! Do not come near prayer when ye are drunk, till you know what you are saying.."** (an-Nisa 4:43)

Whatever doesn't put us in this state of unawareness, despite it being labeled as a drug, isn't forbidden.

Comment: I understand your answer & this much was always clear to me.
"O ye who believe! Do not come near prayer when ye are drunk, till you know what you are saying.." (an-Nisa 4:43) This ayat opens a window to drinking also, maybe in moderation....
Over all i understand that Alcohol is to be avoided cuz of various reasons as You mentioned. But smoking marijuana does not cripple your mind, to my knowledge it enhances your focus & widens your vision to everything & one does not even forget any action in its state of mind afterwards. So how can we bring all those to the same category as Alcohol here

Answer (score -3):

Avoid all forms of alcohol. It's like literally in everything! Search up spirit vinegar and how it's made. It's like in all sauces! May Allah save us from all forms of evil ameen xx

Comment: There is nothing wrong with eating sauce that contains Alcohol as the Alcohol will lose its properties by then (drinking a buck load of the sauce won't make you drunk). Besides, that isn't what the question was asking.